# ElasticSearch Rails: Sort by date1 if it's present and in the future, else sort by date2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

[image]

Above are two different records from a `Posts` model we have stored in elasticsearch. We're trying to put in logic that will put our sticky posts in the feed like regular posts after they've expired.

We want to have it say

"If `is_sticky` AND `stickied_until` is in the future sort by `stickied_until`, else sort by `created_at`"

I think I have it working in SQL (since we store the bulk of the data there and only the searchable fields in ES), which looks like

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
  WHEN stickied_until >= '#{DateTime.now.utc}'
  THEN stickied_until
  ELSE created_at
END DESC
```

but then there's two things controlling the sort, which I'm pretty sure will cause bugs, and also just feels wrong.

Is it possible to do this kind of conditional sorting in ES?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris 5.4 I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a sort script for this.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            def is_sticky = doc['is_sticky'].value;
            def created_at = doc['created_at'].value.getMillis();
            if (!is_sticky) {
              return created_at;
            }

            def stickied_until =  doc['stickied_until'].value.getMillis();
            def now = params['now'];

            if (is_sticky && stickied_until > now) {
              return stickied_until;
            }

            return created_at;
          """,
          "params": {
            "now": 1586798403888
          }
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that I've used query-time constant `params['now']` due to reasons explained in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_now).

Comment: Depending on your ES version, you may need to use `doc['created_at'].date.getMillis()` instead of `doc['created_at'].value.getMillis()`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on ES 5.4 so I did have to change to `doc['created_at'].date.getMillis()`, otherwise this worked like a charm